# html - cache busting using query string results in always downloading the resources

Tags: html

This question may sound duplicate, but I could not get a satisfactory answer after reading through several old questions on this forum. The problem is as follows.

I am replacing a image file ( having same name ). I am not able to see the new image due to caching, which is obvious - Expected behaviour.

So I did cache busting by **manually** adding a query string, 'v=1.0'

```
<img src="slider_img/1.jpg?v=1.0" alt="Image 1" style="width:100%;border-radius: 25px">
```

Now, I could see the new image - Again Expected behavior.

But now, If I again replace the image, **without changing the query string**, I see the newest(latest) image. - Unexpected behavior.
It Indicates that, when a query string is appended, browser is always requesting a new file, even if the query string is not further changed. New image download should have happened only if I had changed the query string to something like

```
<img src="slider_img/1.jpg?v=2.0"
```

Which means, everytime, there would be unnecessary download of image, even if it is not changed.

Is my assumption correct or I am doing something wrong ? Is there any other method of cache busting ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no way with simple html code
you can disable your browser cache from the settings of your browser
may be this could work